# DBset is empty but there is data in db (EF)

Tags: c#, entity-framework

```
public static _Game GetGame(int gameId)
    {
        var game = _entities.Games.Where(gm => gm.Id == gameId).FirstOrDefault();
        return _mapper.Map<_Game>(game);
    }
```

Variable game is null, also if I try to bring the whole table by another query it returns an empty array

Comment: at first, your query just returns the first `Games` object who matches by `gameId`. second, your question is not clear ?! you wanna fetch all `Games` ?! or what ?!

Comment: I want the Game object matches by `gameId`

I did another query to return the whole table and it was empty

but there is data in it

Comment: @Suren can u show the  ```gameId``` which place to come? because of which place to pass this ```gameId``` that is null can u show code?

Comment: _... return the whole table and it was empty but there is data in it_, are you sure the databases are same, please check your connection string.

Comment: Everything's ok with the `gameId` parameter it's `2` when I put a brackpoint and looking the vallues, it comes from request body

Comment: You mention "request body", that sounds like asp.net. Having "_entities" static (and that GetGame method) is probably not what you want. Try rewriting to instance method and variables. Static values are shared between all users of the site!

Comment: It's a WEBapi project and I do not care about sharing something now, also changing them to instance did not help...

I cannot found out .
There aren't articles about it anywhere.